# Laravel left join for polymorphic relation not giving perfect results

Tags: php, laravel, left-join

I have one-to-one polymorphic relation.

```
customer_class_bookings
id | customer_id | status | total | quantity | trader_user_id

Polymorphic table (trader_job_payment)
id | status | payable_id | payable_type
```

My query is

```
 $earnings = CustomerClassBooking::where('trader_user_id', $user_id)
            ->leftjoin('trader_job_payment', function ($q)
            {

                $q->on('trader_job_payment.payable_id', '=', 'customer_class_bookings.id');
                $q->on('trader_job_payment.payable_type', '=', \DB::raw("'" . CustomerClassBooking::class . "'"));
            })
            ->select(
                \DB::raw("SUM(IF (customer_class_bookings.status = 'Completed', customer_class_bookings.quantity, 0)) AS completed"),
                \DB::raw("SUM(IF (trader_job_payment.status = 'DISBURSED' , customer_class_bookings.total, 0)) AS earning"), //problem lies here
                \DB::raw("SUM(IF (customer_class_bookings.status = 'Accepted-Paid' , customer_class_bookings.quantity, 0)) AS pending"),
                \DB::raw("SUM(IF (customer_class_bookings.status IN ('Cancelled', 'Disputed') , customer_class_bookings.quantity, 0)) AS not_completed")
            )
            ->first();
            return $earnings;
```

It all works fine until if we match something with `trader_job_payment` table like in `earnings` section

```
\DB::raw("SUM(IF (trader_job_payment.status = 'DISBURSED' , customer_class_bookings.total, 0)) AS earning"),
```

where it is not giving perfect results as `IF` condition always returns false in that case. Can anybody tell me that what could be the problem here?
**Earning result without left-join**

```
$earning_bookings = CustomerClassBooking::whereHas('payment', function($query){
            $query->where('status','DISBURSED');
        })->where('trader_user_id',$user_id)->sum('total');
```

Comment: make sure that there is a record that really `trader_job_payment.status = 'DISBURSED'`

Comment: @TsaiKoga Yes the record is existed.

Comment: if the records is not too huge, try to select the `->select('trader_job_payment.status')` out, and debug it.

Comment: @TsaiKoga I have done it through manual sql queries and it gives the perfect results. I want to do it with laravel where it is giving the problems.

Comment: can u post your raw sql queries

Comment: I think the problem is your last query. the status is from CustomerClassBooking.

Comment: @TsaiKoga Actually we need to calculate it according to the status of `trader_job_payment ` which is calculating perfectly without left join.

Comment: so I think you need to change your `without leftjoin` to be like this: `CustomerClassBooking::whereHas('payment', function($query){
            $query->where('trader_job_payment.status','DISBURSED');
        })->where('trader_user_id',$user_id)->sum('total');`

Comment: Hmm, I think its already inside the function of relation `payment`